# change names in dots to characters

Tags: r, names, ellipsis

I have a function like this one:

```
my_fun <- function(...,x,y){
  list(...)
}
```

I want to be able to feed variable names OR strings to the ellipsis and convert all to character before returning. In my real case I will call a custom function through `do.call(custom_fun,list(...))`.

**Expected output**

What I'm asking here is a function `my_fun2` that would have the following behavior :

```
my_fun2 <- function(...,x,y){
  MAGIC(list(...))
}

identical(my_fun("a",foo= "b == 3",c("c","d"),bar=c("e","f"),c("g","h")),
          my_fun2("a",foo= b == 3,c("c","d"),bar = c("e",f),c(g,h)))
```

should be `TRUE` and both terms return:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# $foo
# [1] "b == 3"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "d"
# 
# $bar
# [1] "e" "f"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "g" "h"
```

**What I tried...**

```
my_fun2 <- function(...,x,y){
 lapply(pryr::dots(...),as.character)
}

my_fun2("a",b == 3,c("c","d"),c("e",f),c(g,h))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "==" "b"  "3" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "c" "d"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "c" "e" "f"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "c" "g" "h"
```

**Notes**

I don't have a good understanding of expressions, quotes, quosures, calls, names.. so I'll appreciate explanations relevant to the case.

I'm fine with solutions using either (or both!) `base` (`substitute`, `quote` etc) and `dplyr` answers (`enquo`, `quos`etc)

Comment: What about `as.character(substitute(alist(...)))[-1]`?

Comment: `as.character(substitute(alist(...)))[-1]` returns `[1] "a"               "b"               "c(\"c\", \"d\")" "c(\"e\", f)"     "c(g, h)"`, it messes with the vectors.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, this might help: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-dots

Comment: I think `sapply(substitute(alist(...)),as.character)` would have worked before I generalize my question with `b ==3`, it gives me `[1] "==" "b"  "3"` for my 3rd element intead of keeping the element in order (and pasted together), something related to the parsing of the expression I assume

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud but this had to be done...

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(pryr)
my_fun2 <- function(...,x,y){
  dots0 <- as.character(substitute(alist(...)))[-1]
  vectors <- substr(dots0,1,2) == "c("
  dotsv <- dots0[vectors] %>%
    gsub("\"","",.)    %>% 
    gsub("(","('",.,fixed=TRUE)   %>% 
    gsub(", ","', '",.,fixed=TRUE)  %>%
    gsub(")","')",.,fixed=TRUE)  %>%
    map(~eval(parse(text=.x)))
  setNames(c(as.list(dots0[!vectors]),dotsv),names(pryr::dots(...)))
}

identical(my_fun2("a",foo= "b == 3",c("c","d"),bar = c("e","f"),c("g","h")),
my_fun2("a",foo= b == 3,c("c","d"),bar = c("e",f),c(g,h)))
# [1] TRUE

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# $foo
# [1] "b == 3"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "d"
# 
# $bar
# [1] "e" "f"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "g" "h"
```